# Send an object from one Activity to another, after it was started

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to send an object from one activity to another, but **after** `startActivity(i)`.

Example:

**Activity A** calls **Activity B**

Something in background should update an object in **Activity A**, make a copy of that object (as opposed to sending the reference), and send it to **Activity B** (which is already started).

```
<activity
        android:name="gui.GUIConversacion"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="action.action.myactionstring" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

---

```
                Intent intent = new Intent("action.action.myactionstring");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            intent.putExtra("conversacionActualizada",conversacionesCache.get(c));
            startActivity(intent);
```

---

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if ("action.action.myactionstring".equals(intent.getAction())) {
        this.conversacion=(Conversacion) intent.getExtras().get("conversacionActualizada");
        actualizarGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents

Comment: I know this. It is for before to start. I need after start it

Comment: **"Someone in background update a object in Activity A"** - If you've already started Activity B there should be no way that anything in Activity A could be updated.

Comment: `"I know this"` -> please, write down what you know in your Question, so people don't waste time suggesting things *you already know*.

Comment: @b_ he DID start the question explicitly saying that it was after Activity B is started (ie not starting a new activity) so pyus was wrong here

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is send another intent with the extra attached and a flag to say to reuse he activity, it will then call onNewIntent on the receiving activity where you can get that object.

Edit:
It's bad practice to link without summarising, so here's what you need:

In Receiving activity:

```
   public static final String EXTRA_KEY_CONSTANT = "my extra key";

   @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       if ("action.action.myactionstring".equals(intent.getAction())) {
           //TODO: intent.getExtra(EXTRA_KEY_CONSTANT);
       }
   }
```

In receiving activity mainfest

```
   <activity android:name=".MyReceivingActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="action.action.myactionstring" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            ...
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

In the other activity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("action.action.myactionstring");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra(ReceivingActiviy.EXTRA_KEY_CONSTANT, object);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: How is this going to be used in Activity A if Activity B is already started?

Comment: This says how to get A to contact already started B - as the question asked. It's not my concern how Activity A receives the background update and starts this process.

Comment: You miss my point - if Activity A has already started Activity B, i.e., Activity B is visible and running, Activity A will be hidden and, at the very least, in a non-running state - either paused or more usually stopped. It should not be possible for anything in Activity A to be updated nor execute any code in this state.

Comment: I know that @Squonk, but the question asked for "sent an object from an activity to other after startActivity" and the solution that I have provided does that. It's not my place to be concerned with other lifecycle changes outside of that question and his architecture and in any case, you've already made him aware of this

Comment: when I do startActivity(intent) in the other activity, there is an excepction:

Comment: 01-26 16:12:28.397: E/AndroidRuntime(28181): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 16:12:28.397: E/AndroidRuntime(28181): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=action.action.myactionstring flg=0x20000000 (has extras) }
01-26 16:12:28.397: E/AndroidRuntime(28181):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
01-26 16:12:28.397: E/AndroidRuntime(28181):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1423)

Comment: Looks like you haven't set up your intent filter. Edit your question above, attach your manifest and the two other parts you changed to match my example

Comment: I've edited my answer, you'll see I've added a category to the intent filter, in simple terms it means "when this action is looking for an activity, throw my name in the hat", you should also change the action string to something specific to you, containing your package name and the name of the action

Comment: it's running!! thanks you so much!! I have I nullpointer but I think that is for other things! very thanks you!

Comment: If my answer has pointed you in the right direction please mark it as the accepted answer now, thank you